# How to store a very large integer in java

Tags: java

My input is of `10^19 ;` How can i store this number.

```
int input ; // Of order 10^19;
int answer = input%(10^10+3)
```

How to perform above operations and what if i want to have an array

```
A[input][input] // showing me an error
```

Comment: There is a class called BigInteger

Comment: please note that `^` operator is **bitwise XOR** and not actually powering

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check out [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of int, declare it as long. Its maximum value is of 2^63-1

Check this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: BigInteger would be more appropriate in this situation.

Comment: @jbutler483 fair enough. Im a pretty new programmer too.

Comment: We all started up at one point (and are still learning!)

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger input; 
BigInteger answer = input%(10^10+3)
```